# Time is come or Time has come

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I was reading an [article in *The Economist*](https://www.economist.com/briefing/2018/10/13/why-people-in-rich-countries-are-eating-more-vegan-food) and came across the phrase "Perhaps their time is come at last."

> The founder of the first vegan society said in 1944 that "in time [people] will view with abhorrence the idea that men once fed on the products of animals' bodies." Many since have shared his hope. Perhaps their time is come at last.

I googled it but couldn't find any satisfactory reason as to why the author should use "Time **is** come" instead of "Time **has** come". Any ideas?

Comment: It's an archaic usage, sometimes still  employed in a literary context. In the English of three hundred years ago, some verbs formed their perfect with _be_ instead of _have_ (as is the case in French and some other languages). I don't know whay it would be used in that example.

Answer (score 1):

It's an archaic expression, probably sourced from [1 Peter 4:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Peter%204%3A17&version=KJV):

> For the time is come that judgment must begin at the house of God: and
>   if it first begin at us, what shall the end be of them that obey not
>   the gospel of God?

---

At least [one source](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-The-time-has-come-and-The-time-is-come) claims that the difference between "time is come" and "time has come" is that the former **always** means that someone is about to die, while the latter can mean other things too.